# how to make some things impervious to time.sleep() python

Tags: python, function, animation, time, turtle-graphics

My program is split into two functions. Once get data, positions, and color of a bunch of bouncing balls. The other draws these balls and makes them move. What I'm trying to do is make one ball appear every five seconds. In order to do this, I must use time.sleep() on one the data() function, but not the moving() function. Since the two are so closely linked, I cannot figure out how to do this. I think the only way would be either to completely chance the logic of my program (which I don't want to do), or to make the moving() function impervious to time.sleep() somehow. Any ideas?

getData() function:

```
def getData(numobjects):
    for x in range(int(numobjects)):


    xCoordinate.append(random.randint(-300, 300))
    yCoordinate.append(random.randint(-300, 300))

    speed1.append(random.randrange(-8,8))
    speed2.append(random.randrange(-8,8))

    for i in range(len(speed1)):
        for char in range(len(speed2)):
            if i == 0 or char == 0:
                i = random.randint(-8,8)
                char = random.randint(-8,8)

    color.append([random.random(), random.random(), random.random()])
```

*part of the moving()* function:

```
# Clearing the canvas and hiding the turtle for the next iteration of moving()
turtle.clear()
turtle.hideturtle()

# Drawing all of the circles
for i in range(len(xCoordinate)):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(xCoordinate[i], yCoordinate[i])
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.fillcolor(color[i][0], color[i][1], color[i][2])
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(15)        
    turtle.end_fill()
    xCoordinate[i] += speed1[i]
    yCoordinate[i] += speed2[i]
# Bouncing off edges of the screen
    if xCoordinate[i] > 300:
        xCoordinate[i] = 299
        speed1[i] *= -1
    if xCoordinate[i] < -300:
        xCoordinate[i] = -299
        speed1[i] *= -1         
    if yCoordinate[i] > 300:
        yCoordinate[i] = 299 
        speed2[i] *= -1
    if yCoordinate[i] < -300:
        yCoordinate[i] = -299
        speed2[i] *= -1

# updating turtle and running the moving() function every ten milliseconds
turtle.update()
turtle.ontimer(moving, 10)
```

Comment: You could try using the `threading` library to make them run consecutively as different threads.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I'm pretty new to stack overflow, so I hadn't realized that I needed to post my code. However, the code in particular of these two functions is about 200 lines. Should I post all of it?

Comment: Your thread has been put on hold for being off topic actually, so reword your original post with a code example, and a little more description. You should only post the relevent part of your code.

Comment: I hope that makes it a little better

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use `time.sleep()` between balls, why not keep track of elapsed time?

```
start = time.time()
INTERVAL = 5
while True:
    if time.time() >= start + INTERVAL:
        # release new ball
        start = time.time()
    # deal with movements
```

Alternatively, you will have to separate your functions using [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) or [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

Comment: When I try to implement this, something very strange happens: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded. Also, I get a windows error message that says python has stopped working. Neither one of these functions is recursive. I see no logical reason for these errors. If you have any idea why this happened, please leave it in the comments section.

Comment: Nope, if your functions really aren't recursive I can't see why that would happen

Answer (score -1):

You could use the threading library to do this. For instance you can see a nice example using the `time.sleep()` method here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import thread
import time

# Define a function for the thread
def print_time( threadName, delay):
   count = 0
   while count < 5:
      time.sleep(delay)
      count += 1
      print "%s: %s" % ( threadName, time.ctime(time.time()) )

# Create two threads as follows
try:
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-1", 2, ) )
   thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-2", 4, ) )
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"
```

The idea is that you're making the individual threads sleep, and not the entire program.

Comment: `while True: pass` - please not. that'll max out your cpu usage. thanks to the GIL it will also effectively prevent the other threads from soing anyhting.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, I was more focused on the threads part. I edited the above code